# how can i go about using a comboBox value in an object to do a calculation

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a game based on Marcus Du Sautoy's book "Number Mysteries" in which they describe a game where a team of three football players with prime numbers on their shirt use the prime numbers to see whether they beat the opposing side.

Basically, I want to set these three prime numbers on a "Player Selection Screen" and have them stored on each player, how can I go about this?

This is the PlayerSelection.ui

[image: Image of my PlayerSelection UI]

So I want to have the number thats selected in the comboBox to be set to a "player" object and if there is no number selected in one of the comboBoxes I want an error message to appear when the user presses the "Play" button so that they can't continue unless they pick three numbers.
I don't have much code written that does this function because I just can't find any tutorial video or article that explains a method to do what I want to do.
PlayerSelection.cpp below.

```
#include "playerselection.h"
#include "ui_playerselection.h"

PlayerSelection::PlayerSelection(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PlayerSelection)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setStyleSheet("PlayerSelection {background-image:url(:/PrimeFootballBkgnd.jpg)}");
}

PlayerSelection::~PlayerSelection()
{
    delete ui;
}

void PlayerSelection::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
//    hide();
//    MainMenu mainMenu;
//    mainMenu.setModal(true);
    this->hide();
    QWidget *parent = this->parentWidget();
    parent->show();
}

void PlayerSelection::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //if()
    widget = new Widget(this);
    widget->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PlayerSelection` object should have signals for every value change it provides, and then the `Player` object should have a slot that is used to receive that value and update its internal state appropriately.

The `PlayerSelection` object would need a state variable that describes whether any of the selections were made. That state variable can be simply the state of the `Play` button: make it disabled by default, and only enable it when the relevant signal was emitted. If `Play`'s enable condition would depend on multiple combo boxes, then having three booleans as state variables could work, and any time they got changed, the `Play`'s enabled property would be set to a logical *and* of those three booleans. There are other ways of doing it, for example using an explicit `QStateMachine`, but it may be too much complication at this point of your journey.

Comment: thank you very much would the signal be the "currentIndexChanged()" that the play button state is dictated by?